# Не работает Shown в C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Работаю сейчас в формах C#. У меня есть две формы. Хочу, чтобы как только нажимается кнопка в первой форме, открывалась вторая форма и выполнялся код после вывода этой формы. Я использовал метод Shown, но по какой-то причине он не работает. Включается только, если поставить в самом начале метода MessageBox.

```
private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        float h;
        int division = 10;
        Graphics gr = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        Pen p = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Gray);
        //Разметка
        h = 0;
        while (h <= pictureBox1.Width)
        {
            gr.DrawLine(p, h, 0, h, pictureBox1.Height);
            h += division;
        }
        h = 0;
        while (h <= pictureBox1.Height)
        {
            gr.DrawLine(p, 0, h, pictureBox1.Width, h);
            h += division;
        }
        //Координатная ось
        p.Color = Color.Red;
        gr.DrawLine(p, pictureBox1.Width / 2, 0, pictureBox1.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Height);
        gr.DrawLine(p, 0, pictureBox1.Height / 2, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height / 2);


    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы поняли, что он не работает и что ожидаете от него?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, результат должен быть как на втором изображении. В pictureBox должна быть сделана разметка и проведены оси. Вместо этого он, видимо, пропускает код, а обращает внимание только если есть MessageBox.

Comment: все просто. Форма может быть перерисована после обработки вашего кода. Так как в основном методе отрисовки нет ни каких упоминаний о вашей разметке - форма возвращается в исходное состояние.

Comment: @rdorn, хорошо. Как перерисовать после обработки?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Неправильно вы бутерброд едите".

**Несколько важных моментов:**

- изображение, нарисованное на форме, нигде не сохраняется, следовательно, при следующей перерисовке формы будет потеряно.
- форма будет принудительно перерисована при открытии, изменении размера, перекрытии вашей формы другой формой, вызове метода `Invalidate()` в коде.
- за отрисовку формы отвечает виртуальный метод `Control.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs)` и событие `Control.Paint`.

**Проблемы вашего кода**

Вы рисуете в событии, которое вызывается один единственный раз, и нигде не запоминаете, что нарисовали. Следовательно, при любом обновлении формы вы получите исходное изображение.

**Пути решения**

Вариантов несколько:

1. **Переопределить `OnPaint` или использовать обработчик события `Paint`**. Собственно событие `Paint` вызывает метод `OnPaint` и все дополнительные методы, которые на него подписаны. Событие срабатывает при любой перерисовке формы. Переносим ваш код рисования в соответствующий метод и радуемся... но не все так просто. Это, наверное, самый очевидный вариант, но и самый сложный в плане правильной реализации, так как от этого будет напрямую зависеть и внешний вид вашей формы, и ее производительность. Код отрисовки должен быть максимально быстрым, без тяжелых вычислений, добывания данных и прочей ерунды. Плюс, вам придется вручную учитывать положение дочерних элементов на форме, что тоже не самое интересное занятие.
2. **Рисуем картинку и вставляем в форму**. Тут все совсем тривиально. Берем `Bitmap` нужного размера, получаем из него объект `Graphics` и рисуем все, что нам надо. После этого вставляем в форму в виде отдельного контрола или сохраняем в каком-нибудь поле формы и переносим изображение на нужный участок с помощью `DrawImage` в `OnPaint`. `DrawImage` реализован нативными средствами и работает очень быстро, но ему нужно готовое изображение. К слову, `DrawImage` тоже можно заставить долго "думать", например, скормив ему очень большую, по размерам в пикселях, картинку с указанием сильно ее уменьшить. Данный способ всем хорош, кроме одного - не подходит для динамических изображений в реальном времени (относительно реальном разумеется). Зато с сохранением изображения в файл вообще никакой мороки - `Bitmap.Save` =).
3. **Кастомный контрол**. Этот вариант мне наиболее симпатичен, так как позволяет сделать работу один раз и пользоваться результатами, когда понадобится.

   Идея в следующем:

   - создаем наследника `UserControl` (в дальнейшем `MyControl`).
   - в `MyControl` добавляем приватные поля для хранения объектов, которые необходимо рисовать. Часть данных может быть постоянной, часть пользовательской, по желанию.
   - в `MyControl` переопределяем `OnPaint` таким образом, чтобы он рисовал хранящиеся внутри объекты в нужном порядке.
   - добавляем публичные свойства, для приема необходимых для отрисовки параметров и объектов.

   Все. Теперь осталось только положить наш кастомный контрол на форму и передать ему необходимые параметры, все остальное он сделает уже сам. Как, собственно, и поступают все стандартные и не очень контролы.

   Данный вариант - нечто среднее между первым и вторым вариантами по сложности, но в отличие от них может быть легко переиспользован при качественной реализации.

---

Вроде ничего существенного не забыл, но если что-то описано не совсем понятно, дайте знать - уточню =)

Comment: Не думал, что мой вопрос вообще достоин такого подробного, аналитического ответа. Можете скинуть книжки или статьи, где рассказано о всех этих способах более подробно, особенно о третьем?

Comment: @ОлегФедоров да нет таких книжек. Просто опыт. К тому же WinForms довольно старая технология, а раз не модно, зачем писать книжки. Так что MSDN  в помощь, увы. Какие именно подробности интересуют?

Comment: @ОлегФедоров некоторые подробности можно получить в любой книге, где так или иначе описана работа в WinForms, у того же Тролсена  например, но все равно придется собирать по кусочкам.

Comment: Как вообще убедиться, что я, допустим, пишу ахинею? Так ведь же бардак в голове и в коде будет.

Comment: @ОлегФедоров В любой программе есть вход и есть выход. Если у вас удалось сделать так, как надо - то ахинеи первого рода (писать неработающие программы) нет,  возможна только ахинея второго рода, когда от входа до выхода шли через избыточные шаги, которые можно сократить. Самое смешное, когда человеку рекомендуют (например, коллеги или на стеке) убрать лишние шаги, а он отмахивается, потому что не доверяет новому коду или не понимает ненужность шагов "из Москвы лететь в Питер через Владивосток".

Comment: Хотя стоп, есть ещё структурная ахинея - когда пользуются чем-то, не понимая, как оно под капотом устроено (например, async/await) и ленятся разобрать на тривиальных программах внутреннее устройство, понять логику работы -- а сразу хреначат код в продакшене, который вроде работает, но иногда чудит по непонятным причинам. Тот случай, когда домчались за пять минут - но потом день потеряли, а надо было сначала день потерять, а потом за пять минут долететь. Хотя обычно долетят за пять минут и годами не хотят потерять день, откладывают на "когда-нибудь потом".

Comment: @AK, все эти виды ахинеи я видел. В первом случае иногда бывает, что код работает, но находится такое исключение для него, которое просто-напросто не замечаешь. Тем более, когда этих исключений в достатке. Досадно. В целом, я вас всех понял. Попробую все эти способы.

Comment: @rdorn Отличный ответ. (Взял на себя смелость убрать некоторые пробелы.)

Comment: @Igor спасибо, не всегда хватает терпения вычитать напечатанное, писать намного легче в этом плане =)